# ArcGIS. Coordinates conversion from WGS84 to Stereo70 is not precise

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-android

So I want to convert coordinates from WGS84 to Stereo 70 and it is not working precise.
For example, I have the coordinates (20.2600, 43.6200) and in Stereo 70 should look like (448469.26,325966.67) but when I convert it, it gives me an error.

My line of code looks like:

```
Log.e("stereo70", " " + GeometryEngine.project(24.3512, 44.4316, SpatialReference.create(31700)));
```

Output: 448464.6330154536, 325965.9619150401
Which is about 30m away from the original point.

I have also tried a code provided in the answer:

```
        Point p = new Point(24.3512, 44.4316);
        Geometry projectedGeom = GeometryEngine.project(p, SpatialReference.create(SpatialReference.WKID_WGS84), SpatialReference.create(31700), GeographicTransformation.create(15995));
        Point projectedP = (Point) projectedGeom;
        Log.e("test", "X:" + projectedP.getX() + " Y:" + projectedP.getY());
```

Output: 448222.593914864 Y:325897.33784212614
Which is an error of about 300m.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Now this Q has become a moving target. (1) you've got different lat-lon coordinates. I think the first set should be the same as the ones later, right? (2) you've switched from 3844 (Pulkovo 1942(58) Stereo 70) to 31700 (Dealul Piscului 1970 Stereo 70). I think that's why tfm 15995 didn't work. It's for 3844, not 31700. With 31700, I was able to get a little closer using 1996, but not spot-on.

Comment: If you can clear up those 2 issues (try tfm 1996 instead for one), I'll rewrite my answer. We may not be able to match your test point. If it's a geodetic control point, a tfm designed for the whole country just won't match. Or the test points were generated using some other tfm that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply the geographic transformation too. In the [10.2.5 API](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geometry/GeometryEngine.html), project has several versions. You're going to have to switch to one that uses a Geometry and supports a GeographicTransformation instead like:

```
public static Geometry  project (Geometry geometry, SpatialReference inputSR, SpatialReference outputSR, GeographicTransformation tx)
```

For the GeographicTransformation, you should use EPSG::15995 which converts between Pulkovo 1942(58) and WGS 1984. The [EPSG Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org) reports that the accuracy is about 3 m. It may be better than that in many places.

Disclosure: I work for Esri and am on the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG Registry.

Comment: Thank you for your help, mkennedy, I will look into that, can you give me an example on my case in the meanwhile?

Comment: I have been trying like this but I don't understand it clearly, can you guide me into the right direction?

com.esri.core.geometry.Point p = new com.esri.core.geometry.Point(20.2600, 43.6200);
        Log.e("stereo70", " " + GeometryEngine.project(p, SpatialReference.create(31700), SpatialReference.create(3844), GeographicTransformation.create(15995)));

Comment: The issue is with your inputSR, you are using Stero_70 as inputSR when it should be WGS84.  I fixed the code below:

    Point p = new Point(20.2600, 43.6200);

    Geometry projectedGeom = GeometryEngine.project(p,
                SpatialReference.create(SpatialReference.WKID_WGS84),
                SpatialReference.create(3844),
                GeographicTransformation.create(15995));
    Point projectedP = (Point)projectedGeom;
    Log.e(TAG, "X:" + projectedP.getX() + " Y:" + projectedP.getY());

Which results in X:117309.97594706231  Y:246664.219546377.

Comment: Not being precise at all. I used a set of coordinates (24.3512, 44.4316) and it gives me (X:448222.593914864 Y:325897.33784212614) instead of (X:448469.26 Y:325966.67) which is an error of about 100m or so.